# Change attribute of custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, paging

I have custom directive to load pages inside a div

```
.directive('page', function () {
    return {
        templateUrl: function (elem, attr) {
            return 'pages/page-' + attr.num + '.html';
        }
    };
});
```

here is the dom representation of the custom directive

```
<div page num="{{pageNo}}"></div>
```

Here i want to change the page number from the controller.

Directive works fine if the value added directly

```
<div page num="1"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you want the interpolated value of `pageNo` inside your directive, You cant get that value inside the `templateUrl` function. You need to use `ng-include` directive to get the value of scope name inside your directive.

**Markup**

```
<div page num="{{pageNo}}"></div>
```

**Code**

```
app.directive('page', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      num: '@'
    },
    template: '<div ng-include="\'pages/page-\'+ num + \'.html\'"></div>'
  };
});
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/VASBrsIwUHaiHjAeMGco?p=preview)

Comment: Will not work. What is local `num` variable in your code?

Comment: @dfsq frankly speaking I didn't get your point..could you please brief it more..local `num` variable came from isolated scope of directive..and it has get its value by evaluating `{{pageNo}}` of `num` attribute

Comment: Thanks for the this. I need to change the value of num from the controller. pageNo is the expression needs to be changed and the corresponding value need to be append to the URL.

Comment: @balajig could you give some plunkr, so that I can proceed my further help with the working example

Comment: @balajig take a look at the updated plunkr & answer.. Thanks :)

Comment: @PankajParkar I have checked the plunker. couldn't see the update. Can you please check again and post.

Comment: @balajig its there..by clicking on the button its change the page template

Comment: @balajig Glad to help you..Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#template-expanding-directive):

> You do not currently have the ability to access scope variables from the templateUrl function, since the template is requested before the scope is initialized.

This means you only have access to the literal value of the attribute and you cannot evaluate it against a certain scope. You might be able to define your directive inside a closure and access the parent scope this way. Then you could call `scope.$eval('pageNo')`.

**However**: This would be a really ugly hack. I'd rather choose the solution with `ng-include` suggested by @pankaj-parkar