# Evaluate attrs in templateUrl

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to read the value of an attr in the templateUrl function of my directive.

```
<my-dirc type="type"></my-dirc>
```

my-dirc :

```
return {
scope : {
  type : =
},
templateUrl: function(elem, attrs) {
  console.log(attrs.type);
}
}
```

however, the console return "type" only and not the value of type.
i have also tried doing

```
<my-dirc type="{{type}}"></my-dirc>
my-dirc :

    return {
    scope : {
      type : @
    },
    templateUrl: function(elem, attrs) {
      console.log(attrs.type);
    }
    }
```

Now the console.log gives me {{type}}.

How can I get the value of type?

Comment: what you are going to to based on type?

Comment: on the basis of type ill return a string which would be the path to the required template.

Comment: Do you want to do a one time change of the template? Or do you want the template to change every time the attribute value changes?

Answer (score 0):

You can't get access to `scope` of the parent, here inside `templatUrl` function. Because `template`/`templateUrl` function gets evaluated first before creating controller scope, that's the reason why you are getting raw value inside your attribute. If you have pass hardcoded value inside `attribute` then only you can retrieve that inside function.

This issue can only be solved using `ng-include`

```
templateUrl: function(elem, attrs) {
   return '<div ng-include="type? \'template\'+type+\'.html\': \'\'"></div>`
}
```

Comment: Cant use ng-include... since this will add a level of scope heirarchy

Comment: is there way to use $interpolate or anything?

Comment: @BhumiSinghal you can do that, it needs scope..because `scope` isn't available at instance.. `templateUrl` is first thing to get evaluate by compiler.. you could find similar [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32410273/2435473)

Comment: @BhumiSinghal may why don't you follow `Dot rule` while defining models

Comment: legacy code .. cant change it all. Compile function can help ?

Comment: or if we can use elem to get the scope using angular.element

Comment: No then go for custom directive which will work same as like ng-include without creating a child scope

Comment: thinking over the usage of custom directive

Comment: So where you are stubled now?

Answer (score -2):

You dont need to write type in expression
Try this

```
<my-dirc type="type"></my-dirc>
```

DIR :

```
return {
  scope : {
  type : '=type'
},
  templateUrl: '.html'

  'link' : function(elem, attrs) {
  attrs.$observe('type', function (obs) {
        console.log(obs);
  })
  } 
}
```

Comment: @PankajParkar you should definately go through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14907826/4286411)

Comment: no man..`templateUrl: '.html'` will fail..and this obivious thing that we can get `type` value inside `link` function.. but there is no need to have `$observe` on it then.. because we are accepting it using `isolated scope` already.. Though this is not what OP wants & it wouldn't solve problem which has been faced by OP

Comment: true.. this will not help